# Fail early if JIRA credentials are incorrect

Tags: python, jira

I am connecting to JIRA using the jira python package:

```
def connect_to_JIRA():
'''
    Generic function to get JIRA connection
'''
if settings.JIRA_AVAILABLE:
    try:
        jira_conn = JIRA(
            basic_auth=(settings.JIRA_USER, settings.JIRA_PASSWORD),
            server=settings.JIRA_SERVER
        )

        return jira_conn
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Unexpected problem connecting to JIRA")
        raise
else:
    log.error("JIRA credentials not configured or incomplete")
    raise
```

Which works fine, but if the credentials are incorrect (not missing) then it goes through a 1-2 minute long song and dance:

```
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET [my jira server address], will retry [1/3] in 1.7998166159998785s. Err: 401 Unauthorized
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET [my jira server address], will retry [2/3] in 39.04052373359595s. Err: 401 Unauthorized
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from GET [my jira server address], will retry [3/3] in 46.35106211454652s. Err: 401 Unauthorized
```

before finally triggering my except clause. Is there any way to make it "fail fast"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `max_retries` to 1. Current default is `3`.

```
jira_conn = JIRA(
        basic_auth=(settings.JIRA_USER, settings.JIRA_PASSWORD),
        server=settings.JIRA_SERVER,
        max_retries=1
    )
```

Comment: Ah hah! I was only looking at the options dict and neglected the __init__() parameters. Thanks!